# What IF / OR formula in excel can calculate duration between a specific date and today, or between two specific dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I'm not sure if this is possible but here is what I would like to do if anyone knows a formula please.

I want to show the duration (in weeks) that a Case is is/was open based on:
a) between the Date Opened and TODAY (if Date Closed is blank)
OR
b) between the Date Opened and Date Closed (if Date Closed is not blank)
OR
c) leave blank if start date is blank

My columns are:
A 'Case', B 'Date Opened', C 'Date Closed', D 'Duration (in weeks)'

See image for example

Thanks, Eva

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question might get closed.

Comment: Just to comment, explore IF , DATEDIF & TODAY functions in Excel.

Comment: Have a look at daysbetween function or https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following formula.

`=IF(B2<>"",IF(C2<>"",DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d")/7,DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"d")/7),"")`

[image]